# I need a REGEX for one of 3 EXACT ALPHA Characters followed by 9 digits

Tags: regex

This will be quick.

I need a pattern for either:
XC123456789 or
SS123456789

This is what I have and doesn't pass muster on the Online Regex checker

```
/^[SXC]{2}\d[0-9]{11}$/
```

Thank you

Comment: This matches 12 digits `\d[0-9]{11}` instead of 9

Comment: Can the number have leading zeroes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `XC` and `SS` are the only two possible combinations then you could do something along the lines of:

```
/^(SS|XC)\d{9}$/
```

This pattern matches either `SS` or `XC` followed by 9 digits.

Answer (score 2):

You were close:

```
^[SXC]{2}[0-9]{9}$
```

This will catch two of any character inside [SXC] in any order followed by any nine digit between 0-9.